# Can you have a datawindow that runs more than one SQL?

Tags: sql, radio-button, powerbuilder, datawindow

I'm pretty new to programming and PowerBuilder in general.  I was wondering if it's possible to have one datawindow but multiple SQL statements? I would like it to run one statement if one radio button is chosen or another statement if a different radio button is chosen. Is this possible or would I have to create more than one datawindow?  If possible what would the steps be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this, and it typically depends on how different the two SQL statements are.
If you're just running a different arguments to a WHERE clause, then you can most likely use one datawindow, and pass in different retrieval arguments.

If they're read-only, you can modify the SQL statement at runtime with SetSQLSelect().

If they're returning completely different result sets, or use a completely different set of tables in the query, then you'll most likely have to use two different datawindows.

-Paul-

Comment: Typically you would modify the SQL in the sqlpreview event on the datawindow (say if you were changing the WHERE clause depending upon the radiobutton the user chose as in your example).

Comment: Paul, thanks for the reply.  I figured I would go with the SetSQLSelect() method, but i'm running into an issue.  My original dataobject has the following syntax:

Comment: Paul, thanks for the reply.  I figured I would go with the SetSQLSelect() method, but i'm running into an issue.  My original dataobject has the following syntax:

    SELECT d.obj_id,   
         d.obj_usr_num,   
         p.ins_tmsp,   
         p.pol_flg,   
         p.ext_flg,   
         p.ext_tmsp  
    FROM pd2_buffer_pmo p,   
         dsk_obj d  
    WHERE ( p.obj_id = d.obj_id ) and  
         ( ( p.obj_type = 'D94' ) )

Comment: This will return when my radio button, rb_all, is selected.  I'm trying to use the SetSQLSelect with my other radio button, rb_document, which will enable sle_document and run the original query but where a document number equals the value in sle_document.  Please see syntax below:

    string DocNum
    integer i_count, m_rtn, i_rtn
    long a_count, l_rtn, l_obj_id

    //Getting total row count from the buffer table.

    SELECT count(*)
    INTO :a_count
    FROM pd2_buffer_pmo
    WHERE obj_type = 'D94'
    USING SQLCA;

Comment: //If there are rows and the Retrieve All Docs radio button is selected, verify if user wants to return all document then
    //retrieve all rows in the buffer table.

    IF a_count > 0 AND rb_all.Checked = TRUE THEN
 m_rtn = MessageBox("Return All Documents?", 'There are ' + string (a_count) + ' documents in the buffer table. The system may process for an extended period of time when returning all documents.  Do you wish to continue?', Question!, YesNo!)
   IF m_rtn = 1 THEN
    dw_buffer.SetTransObject(SQLCA)
    dw_buffer.Retrieve(SQLCA)
   ELSE
    Return 0
   END IF

Comment: //OPEN(w_adapter_buffer_result)
    //RETURN 0

    END IF 


    //If there are currently no rows at all in the buffer table, produce this message.
    IF a_count = 0 AND rb_all.Checked = TRUE THEN
 MessageBox("No Documents!", 'There are no documents in the buffer table.', StopSign!)

    RETURN 0

    END IF

    If rb_document.Checked = True Then


  select obj_id
  into :l_obj_id
  from dsk_obj where obj_usr_num = :gx_s_doc_nmbr
  and obj_type = 'D94'
  using sqlca;

Comment: You can get away with a single datawindow in this case.

Comment: Use your dw that has the retrieval argument, but change the WHERE clause to:

WHERE ((obj_usr_num = :gx_s_doc_nmbr) OR (:gx_s_doc_nmbr = 'ALL'))  and obj_type = 'D94'

Now, if the rb_all is checked ON, set gx_s_doc_nmbr to 'ALL'.  If it's off, you're already setting that variable to an actual doc nmbr value.

Then just call dw_1.retrieve( :gx_s_doc_nmbr )

Comment: @NoazDad  Thank you for all of your help!  I was able to get it work!  Do you happen to have any recommendations as to sites or books to better learn to program in PowerBuilder?